# How to add another deployment configuration with halyard?

Tags: spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

```
root@fe7443a7ebbb:/workdir# hal --version
0.43.0-180317140630
```

The first command I ran with halyard was:

```
hal config provider kubernetes enable
```

This created a default configuration:

```
# ~/.hal/config
currentDeployment: default
deploymentConfigurations:
- name: default
...
```

I'm wondering how to add another deployment configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.spinnaker.io/reference/halyard/commands/#hal-config

> --set-current-deployment: If supplied, set the current active deployment to the supplied value, creating it if need-be.

Example:

```
hal config --set-current-deployment docker-desktop
```

This creates two deployment configurations:

```
# ~/.hal/config
currentDeployment: docker-desktop
deploymentConfigurations:
- name: default
...
- name: docker-desktop
  version: ''
  providers:
```